Mazda overheated, is it fixable?
I have a 2008 Mazda 3. I was driving and it overheated, I found no oil so I filled it up and it wouldn’t start. Earlier, while driving the accelerator quit working and my music was up so I couldn’t tell if the car shut off so I went ahead and shut the key off and turned it back on, the accelerator worked again so I aheaded home. On the way is when it started getting hot and I was always told to turn the heater on full blast so I did and it just kept getting hotter. I pulled over at the first safe place and once again the accelerator quit so I shut the car back off and called for help. I raised the hood cause there was a little smoke. When that was clear I checked fluids and the oil was dry, I am notorious for not keeping up with my fluids. I had a friend try and he said it was over winding? Like when you turn the key to start a vehicle it goes for a second then starts, mine won’t start, jut winds, so he said timing belt. Checked my spark plugs and 3 and 4 were good, 2 had a little bit of fluid but 1 I guess the bolt was stripped so i don’t know about that one. I am incredibly broke, so I’m really not wanting to give up just yet and look for another clunker when I was lucky to have came across this one. Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
